Is it possible to isolate specular highlights in shader nodes?
I am trying to have Blender replicate a shader effect from Valve's Source Engine that applies color mapping to an object's specular highlights. Is it possible to extract/isolate the brightness of the specular reflection in the range from 0 to 1 using Blender's shader nodes?
